# Partitioning my drive is no longer possible - Dual-boot Ubuntu with Kali-Linux is problematic

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lvm

**Objective :** dual-boot Kali-Linux and Ubuntu.

[image]

My problem is located on the drive `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. This is a LVM drive, and because of that, I'm not able to resize that partition in order to get another partition to install Kali Linux (without VM!). In fact, I know as it is a LVM drive I could modify it, but I passed a lot of time trying to do that. Now, I'm giving up trying to modify this partition.

Actually, all I want it's to modify `/dev/nvmen1p5` in such a way I could reinstall Ubuntu  with `/boot`, `/` and  `/home` partition. So, even if I'll kill the OS, I want to modify my drive such as I could install Ubuntu correctly (without LVM partition). Could anyone be able to help me at this point?

Is it possible to force deleting or unmounting a partition? `sudo umount -l /dev/nvme0n1p5` is sufficient?

Comment: What error are you receiving on trying to modify the size of  `/dev/nvme0n1p5`

Comment: Sorry @George, I don't want to take this path.

Comment: Ok, you simply want to do a re-install of Ubuntu and setup the HDD to accommodate Kali linux ?

Comment: Yes, It should be very appreciated!!!

Comment: I have posted a possible solution from the web, but please backup your system before proceeding.

Comment: You could have used KDE Partition Manager 3.0 to resize LVM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**

**Please back up your system and read through first before carrying out**

**Points to note:**

```
- installation mode of Ubuntu
- number of partitions created in Kali Linux
- see third option
```

To create a dual bootable HDD for Kali Linux and Ubuntu.

Methods:

1. Preferably if you have already *installed Ubuntu in legacy mode* then install the Linux in the same mode.

   Step1:

   ```
   Make a bootable live USB with kalilinux and follow the boot setup
   instructions to set boot priority #1 as live USB
   ```

   Step2:

   ```
   Here you can choose either try Kali live or graphical install.
   ```

   Step3:

   ```
   If you choose try Kali live and like to proceed for the installation press
   window+s on keyboard and in the search column type install 
   select install option and follow the instructions properly.
   ```

   Step4:

   ```
   While partition the disk make sure that you have to make three partitions one for swap area, one for root and the other one for home.
   Swap area:4gb space is enough, /root minimum 6gb and /home.
   ```

   Step5:

   ```
   After the partition continue to the installation and grub is installed 
   automatically check whether Ubuntu is is detected by the kalilinux grub. 
   If in case not detected do boot repair with live USB in kalilinux
   to load grub menu
   ```
2. If Ubuntu is in uefi mode then install kalilinux in legacy mode and follow the same procedure for the installation.
3. **This option works best when creating things fresh**:

   step1:

   ```
   Create Ubuntu live CD and use gparted to wipe out the existing partitions.
   ```

   step2:

   ```
   Then create two partitions of equal sizes.
   ```

   step3:

   ```
   Install Kali first and point it at one of the partitions.
   ```

   step4:

   ```
   Then installed Ubuntu but don't choose the install alongside Kali option
   which would divide the 350GB partition Kali was on. Choose the something
   else option and point Ubuntu at the other partition. After the installation 
   both should be in GRUB.
   ```

Source:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2337770

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-dual-boot-my-system-using-Ubuntu-and-kali-Linux

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer george! However, I've succeeded by myself to dual-boot after two days. I learnt a lot of stuff, but it takes to long to do that. Some of your ideas have been used in my procedure.